# Compare and push the right value to Array of objects in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop, if-statement

Below two questions look similar but not relevant to my algorithm. Because the problem I faced is quite difficult. And None of the solutions could help me out. So that, I had to post a long descriptive question to seek some mentorships.

1. [Comparing Two Arrays of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635822/comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-for-duplicate-objects-and-push-it-when-its-not)
2. [Comparing Two arrays Before pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633412/comparing-two-arrays-before-adding-an-item-from-one-array-to-another-in-javascri/36633818#36633818)

I have two array objects that look like

```
UsersList = [
0:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u1', userName: 'name1' }
1:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2' }
2:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u3', userName: 'name3' }
3:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', userName: 'name4' }
4:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2' }
5:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', userName: 'name5' }
6:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', userName: 'name6' }
7:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', userName: 'name7' }
8:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', userName: 'name8' }
]

userRoles = [
0:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', roles: 'admin' }
1:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', roles: 'admin' }
2:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', roles: 'user' }
3:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', roles: 'admin' }
4:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', roles: 'user' }
5:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', roles: 'admin' }
6:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', roles: 'admin' }
7:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u9', roles: 'admin' }
]
```

I have to find that the `userId` and `groupId` of `userRoles` belong to `userList` or not. So I used below filter method

```
const result = this._usersList.filter(e =>
  this._usersRoles.some(r => e.groupId === r.groupId && e.userID === r.userID  ) );
```

above method is filtering my two objects and giving me one `result` object. Something like this.

```
result = [
0:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2' }
1:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', userName: 'name4' }
2:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', userName: 'name7' }
3:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', userName: 'name5' }
4:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2' }
5:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', userName: 'name8' }
6:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', userName: 'name5' }
]
```

I found the roles of the individual users. Now, I have to assign roles for the matching users into the `userList = []` object. If any particular user doesn't have the role then role property should be null.

So that I tried to use below code

```
if (result) {
  this._usersList.map(e => e['roles'] = this._usersRoles.map(r => r.userRoles) );
}
```

Unfortunately, My first problem began from here. Because the `result` is always true and it's mapping a list of array roles and assigned to usersList object all roles from my `userRoles` object. Something like this

```
UsersList = [
0:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u1', userName: 'name1', roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
1:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
2:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u3', userName: 'name3'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
3:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', userName: 'name4'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
4:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
5:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', userName: 'name5'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
6:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', userName: 'name6'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
7:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', userName: 'name7'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
8:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', userName: 'name8'  roles:['admin','admin','user','admin','user','admin','admin','admin'] }
]
```

But my result should look like this

```
 finalUsersList = [
    0:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u1', userName: 'name1', roles: null }
    1:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2', roles: 'admin' }
    2:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u3', userName: 'name3', roles: null }
    3:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', userName: 'name4', roles: 'admin' }
    4:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2', roles: 'user' }
    5:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', userName: 'name5', roles: 'admin' }
    6:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', userName: 'name6', roles: 'admin' }
    7:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', userName: 'name7', roles: 'user'}
    8:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', userName: 'name8', roles: 'admin' }
    ]
```

And my second problem. Suppose I am the user `(u2)` that belongs to two groups `(g1, g2)`. In `g1` I am the `admin` and in `g2` `user`. Hence I am the `admin` of `g1` I will fetch all `users` who belong to `g1` group. And then, I am the `user` of `g2` group, so I will fetch only those users whose roles are only `admin`. So that I did one method also.

```
if(myLocalStorageUserID === this._finalUsersList.filter(e => e.userId) && this._finalUsersList['roles'] == 'admin' {
const filterGroupIDForAdmin = this._finalUsersList['groupID ']
}
```

So Now I got the filter groupId that's fullfil the two conditions. One is, whether I am belongs to that group and other what the role is.

So Now I did one loop according to group Id and try to fetch the all usersName, Like this

```
for(let i=0; i<this.finalUserList.length; i++) {
if(this.finalUserList[i].groupId == filterGroupIDForAdmin ) {
const userListForWhoseRolesIsAdmin = []
userListForWhoseRolesIsAdmin.push(finalUserList[i].userName)
}
}
```

then I checked other groups. what is my role of that group if 'user' then I will take the `groupID` as well as and loop the `finalUserlist` object then fetch the users whose role is only `admin`. Like this.

```
if(myLocalStorageUserID === this._finalUsersList.filter(e => e.userId) && this._finalUsersList['roles'] == 'user' {
    const filterGroupIDForUser = this._finalUsersList['groupID ']
    }
```

Now I got the filter groupId for role user. And now I will fetch the usersname. I used below code.

```
for(let i=0; i<this.finalUserList.length; i++) {
    if(this.finalUserList[i].groupId == filterGroupIDForUser ) {
    const userListForWhoseRolesIsUser = []
    userListForWhoseRolesIsUser.push(finalUserList[i].userName , finalUserList[i].roles )
    }
    for(let i = 0; i<this.userListForWhoseRolesIsUser.length; i++) {
    const filterUserNameList =  []
    if(this.userListForWhoseRolesIsUser[i].role === 'admin') {
    filterUserNameList.push(userListForWhoseRolesIsUser[i].userName)
    }
 }
```

The Result should be look lik

```
finalUserName = [
    0:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u1', userName: 'name1', roles: null }
    1:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2', roles: 'admin' }
    2:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u3', userName: 'name3', roles: null }
    3:{groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', userName: 'name4', roles: 'admin' }
    5:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', userName: 'name5', roles: 'admin' }
    6:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', userName: 'name6', roles: 'admin' }
    8:{groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', userName: 'name8', roles: 'admin' }
    ]
```

It's a huge cumbersome coding style that I made which is totally wrong. Please guide me to reduce my algorithm complexity as well as to solve my issue. 
Thanks

Comment: You are mapping all the users and their roles, hence the array. Why not simply loop through all the users and add an additional property of role?

Comment: @FortyTwo thanks for the reply. Do you mean in this checking
`if (result) {
  this._usersList.map(e => e['roles'] = this._usersRoles.map(r => r.userRoles) );
}`
But if I do loop then how can I check the userID ?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for all roles and map new objects with the role of `roles`.

```js
function getUsers(user) {
    var groups = finalUsersList
            .filter(({ userId }) => user === userId)
            .reduce((r, { groupId, roles }) => (r[groupId] = roles, r), Object.create(null));

    return finalUsersList
        .filter(({ groupId, roles }) => 
            groups[groupId] === 'admin' ||
            groups[groupId] === 'user' && roles === 'admin'
        );
}

var usersList = [{ groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u1', userName: 'name1' }, { groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2' }, { groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u3', userName: 'name3' }, { groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', userName: 'name4' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', userName: 'name2' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', userName: 'name5' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', userName: 'name6' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', userName: 'name7' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', userName: 'name8' }],
    userRoles = [{ groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u2', roles: 'admin' }, { groupId: 'g1', userId: 'u4', roles: 'admin' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u7', roles: 'user' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u5', roles: 'admin' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u2', roles: 'user' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u8', roles: 'admin' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u6', roles: 'admin' }, { groupId: 'g2', userId: 'u9', roles: 'admin' }],
    roles = userRoles.reduce(
        (m, { groupId, userId, roles }) => m.set([groupId, userId].join('|'), roles),
        new Map()
    ),
    finalUsersList = usersList.map(user => Object.assign(
        {},
        user,
        { roles: roles.get([user.groupId, user.userId].join('|')) || null }
    ));

console.log(finalUsersList);
console.log(getUsers('u2'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, You are the lifesaver. Thanks a lot, Could you please look at my below problem.

Comment: that is the part i do not understand. what is the input and what should be the outcome?

Comment: Ok, Sorry for my fuzzy description. I am trying to explain again. 
You got the FinaluserList Object. Now I have to implement below algorithms.
For that Suppose, My user ID is u2. 
1. I have to check how many groups I belong to. (In FinaluserList object I belong to two groups (g1, g2). Then I will check what is the roles of mine. 
2. My role is admin for group g1. And user for g2. Now I will take the groupID of mine. 
3. Then, where I am admin I will fetch the all username of that groups. So my result should be fetch all user who are belongs to g1. Because I am the admin of g1

Comment: And the second part of the algorithm. I have to check my other roles, like user. For example. In group g2 , My role is user in FinalUserList object. So now, I will take my group ID of mine where I am user. Then I will fetch all users, who are belongs to same group mean g2. and also I will check those users role. Are they are admin or user. If they are admin then I will fetch only those users.

Comment: Tell me if I couldn't explain then I will try again

Comment: so you want to get all users who are in `g1` admins and in `g2` users? what about `roles: null`?

Comment: roles: null, I will take If I am(u2) the admin of that group. I will take all user whether the role is assigned or not. 
If I am (u2) user of any group. then I will take only those users whose role is admin at the same group

Comment: please add for the second part a wanted result (not symbolic, but the real one). and add some other results for other use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nina. I am adding the result.

Comment: You should write a book about Vanilla JavaScript Data Structure and Algorithm. Salute

Comment: please see the result of `getUsers('u2')`.

Comment: Yes, it's a 100% correct one. So that I told you 'You should write a book ' :). 
May I ask you one question more? Could you please explain a little the use of reducing method. Actually, I am new in JS world, can't understand how this is working?

Comment: which one? please have a look into the introduction to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Nina.  Suppose my users (u2) has roles === null. So that I want to show only myself, Means only (u2). Then How it will look like. I changed
return this._finalUserList
      .filter(
        ({ groupId, roles }) =>
          groups[groupId] === 'ROLE_ADMIN' ||
          (groups[groupId] === 'ROLE_USER' && roles === 'ROLE_ADMIN') ||  groups[groupId] === null
      )
      .map(({ groupId, userID, userName }) => [
        { groupUuid: groupId, uuid: userID, userName: userName }
      ]);
but it did work. Can you help to figure it out. Why?

Comment: then you need the `userId` as well, because you want only the thios user: `this._finalUserList.filter(({ groupId, userId, roles }) => groups[groupId] === 'ROLE_ADMIN' || (groups[groupId] === 'ROLE_USER' && roles === 'ROLE_ADMIN') || groups[groupId] === null && user === userId).map(({ groupId, userID, userName }) => [{ groupUuid: groupId, uuid: userID, userName: userName }]);` `user` is the parameter of the function.

Comment: Got a, . (groups[groupId] == null && userID === user ). Now it's working

Comment: great. do you have some more questions?